# npm lodash build issues in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, lodash, node-modules

Am trying to build my project and getting many issues related to lodash

I have typescript version 2.0.10 and  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.65"

I have tried replacing 4.14.65 to  "@types/lodash": "ts2.0" as suggested in one of the Git hub issues. Still facing this issue. Any help?

The following is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342978/npm-cannot-find-name-many-and-cannot-find-namespace-from-lodash-library?rq=1

Comment: I checked all the possibilities...nothing worked

Comment: Try something obvious like reinstalling node_modules. I just had similar problem. I reinstalled and problem should not go away, but it happened. :D

Comment: npm install @types/lodash@4.14.50 --save  this solved for me

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying, finally the following command solved my issue.

npm install @types/lodash@4.14.50 --save